# C++: Using ifstream with getline();

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, getline

Check this program

```
ifstream filein("Hey.txt");
filein.getline(line,99);
cout<<line<<endl;
filein.getline(line,99);
cout<<line<<endl;
filein.close();
```

The file Hey.txt has alot of characters in it. Well over a 1000

But my question is
Why in the second time i try to print line. It doesnt get print?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the C++ reference ([here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)) getline sets the `ios::fail` when count-1 characters have been extracted. You would have to call `filein.clear();` in between the `getline()` calls.

Comment: Some explanation of your answer would be great. What is ios::fail and what is going on :D

Comment: i like people like you, Pushing me forward like that. Thanks again

Comment: There are several bits that keep track of the internal state of a stream defined in std::ios_base: goodbit, badbit, failbit, eofbit. When any of the 'bad' bits are set, the stream stops reading and evaluates to false (e.g., used as a `while` condition). That is why Kerrek SB suggested to use the while loop.

Comment: The bits only affect the stream. Nothing really happens to the file.

Answer (score 59):

The idiomatic way to read lines from a stream is this:

```
std::ifstream filein("Hey.txt");

for (std::string line; std::getline(filein, line); ) 
{
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

Notes:

- No `close()`. C++ takes care of resource management for you when used idiomatically.
- Use the free `std::getline`, not the stream member function.

Comment: This actually isnt helping my problem at all

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil: You never check the return value of your input operations, so it's entirely impossible to tell what your program is doing.

Comment: The first time i print out line, it prints out the first 99 chars, but the next time i do that it prints out nothing

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil: See above. If you don't check the error condition after `getline`, *there is no guarantee that anything will be the case*.

Comment: i have to do filein.clear()  between each getline for this to work. Do you know why?

Comment: The problem is that it is considered a failure if there is no newline within the 98 characters and, thus, the stream is put into failure mode, i.e., `std::ios_base::failbit` is set. With this bit set the stream won't extract any characters. Strangely, though, it modifies the character array to store a null character into the next, i.e., the first location.

Comment: This thus is the most idiomatic way one deals with the stream.

Comment: What causes the file to get closed automatically?

Answer (score 3):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
ifstream in;
string lastLine1;
string lastLine2;
in.open("input.txt");
while(in.good()){
    getline(in,lastLine1);
    getline(in,lastLine2);
}
in.close();
if(lastLine2=="")
    cout<<lastLine1<<endl;
else
    cout<<lastLine2<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

As Kerrek SB said correctly There is 2 possibilities:
1) Second line is an empty line
2) there is no second line and all more than 1000 character is in one line, so second `getline` has nothing to get.

Comment: actually even if it was one line, getline should continue where it left off

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to get a line is to use the extractor operator of `ifstream`

```
    string result;
    //line counter
    int line=1;
    ifstream filein("Hey.txt");
    while(filein >> result)
    { 
      //display the line number and the result string of reading the line
      cout << line << result << endl;
      ++line;
    }
```

One problem here though is that it won't work when the line have a space `' '` because it is considered a field delimiter in `ifstream`. If you want to implement this kind of solution change your field delimiter to e.g. `-` `/` or any other field delimiter you like.

If you know how many spaces there is you can eat all the spaces by using other variables in the extractor operator of ifstream. Consider the file has contents of first name last name.

```
    //file content is: FirstName LastName
    int line=1;
    ifstream filein("Hey.txt");
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    while(filein>>firstName>>lastName)
    {
      cout << line << firstName << lastName << endl;
    }
```