# passing ifstream object to function and use getline() in between

Tags: c++, function, fstream, file-handling, getline

I want to open a file named 1.board by calling a function and use getline function to print it's characters to new line.But this is showing a lot of errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using std::ifstream;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

void ReadBoardFile(ifstream& search)
{
  string line;
  search.open("1.board");
  while(getline("1.board",line))
  {
    cout<<line<<"\n";
  }
}

int main() {
  ifstream fin;
  ReadBoardFile(fin);
}
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong.I just can't find a perfect and exact answer.
Help,if you can.Thanku!!!!!

Comment: What is wrong exactly? Did you try to look for similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133379/c-using-ifstream-with-getline, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line-using-ifstream-in-c

Comment: Please, have a look into doc. [std::getline()](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). `std::getline()` expects a stream as 1st arg. but you provided a const C string (`"1.board"`). Shouldn't it be `getline(search, line)`?

Comment: And, if it still isn't accepted then try `std::getline(search, line);`. I appreciate that you tried to prevent `using namespace std;` but all the `using`s at begin of your code appear more tedious to me than just prefixing all standard stuff just by `std::`. ;-)

Comment: thank u very much.it solved my problem @Scheff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's your code rewritten so it works.

Two changes, first the first parameter to `getline` should be the stream you are reading from not the name of a file. I'm guessing that you just weren't concentrating when you wrote that.

Second change, I've moved the stream variable `search` so that it is local to your `ReadBoardFile` function. There's no reason in the code you've posted to pass that in as a parameter. You might want to pass the name of the file as a parameter, but I'll leave you to make that change.

```
void ReadBoardFile()
{
  ifstream search("1.board");
  string line;
  while(getline(search,line))
  {
    cout<<line<<"\n";
  }
}

int main() {
  ReadBoardFile();
}
```

Comment: thank u and u were right I was not concentrating at that time. And suppose if I passed the file name as a parameter to the function then how can I receive it?

Comment: @GautamGoyal Like this `void ReadBoardFile(const char* filename) { ifstream search(filename); ...`.